# Adding CameraInstance() to view

Tags: android, view, android-framelayout, android-sdk-2.3

Trying to add the feed from the phone camera to a view so I can display it. I've been following a tutorial and have solved all the other issues except this one. This is the code in question:

```
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;

public CameraPreview(CameraPreview context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
mCamera = getCameraInstance();
mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
preview.addView(mPreview);
}
```

and I'm receiving the error:

```
Error:(63, 25) error: incompatible types: CameraPreview cannot be converted to View
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated, I'll also post more of the code if people want to see it. It is essentially just this tutorial though: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Comment: did you extand surfaceView ?

Comment: As per the edit, it looks like you've removed the onCreate method (where the problem was) all together. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah this fixed some things. Quick additional question, the "super(context)"  points to an activity in the main.java because I put a constructor there for it, is that all right and if so what should be in that constructor?

Answer (score 0):

try usinng this instead of your camera preview

```
 public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        private Camera mCamera;

        public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            mCamera = camera;

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
            try {
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("camera", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

            if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
                return;
            }

            try {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            } catch (Exception e){
            }
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();

            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("camera", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep I've got this. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: No I had this beforehand, should have pointed it out. The issue remains.